# How to pass a javascript blob to java using getState in JavascriptComponent to Java byte[]?

Tags: javascript, java, blob, audio-recording, vaadin7

I am trying to create a custom javascript component in vaadin using to capture audio from the web browser and pass the saved javascript blob to java to save it in database.

My question is, how to pass that blob and convert it to a java readable type?